# How to setup a default signature for a Shared Mailbox in Exchange and Outlook

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365

In this scenario, we have users who use a primary user mailbox as well as a shared mailbox.  They wish to have default signatures for each mailbox.  However, when going into Outlook Options > Mail > Signatures, only the user mailbox appears as selectable for configuring a signature.  The shared mailbox does not have a way to select a default signature.

Does anyone know how to configure a default signature for a Shared Mailbox?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook on the Desktop requires a mailbox to be added explicitly (*manually* in the instructions below). Not implicitly via Auto Provisioning. Only then are you able to set it a signature as a default.

Instructions on how to do it are here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/open-and-use-a-shared-mailbox-in-outlook-d94a8e9e-21f1-4240-808b-de9c9c088afd

> #### What if it didn't work?
>
> ```
> If your admin only recently added you to a shared mailbox, it may take a few minutes before the shared mailbox appears. Wait a bit and
> ```
>
> then close and restart Outlook again.
>
> ```
> If that didn't work, then manually add the shared mailbox to Outlook:
>
>     Open Outlook.
>
>     Choose the File tab in the ribbon.
>
>     Choose Account Settings, then select Account Settings from the menu.
>
>     Select the Email tab.
>
>     Make sure the correct account is highlighted, then choose Change.
>
>     Choose More Settings > Advanced > Add.
>
>     Type the shared email address, such as info@contoso.com.
>
>     Choose OK > OK.
>
>     Choose Next > Finish > Close.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge, you could add a disclaimer as a **[signature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/policy-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/signatures?view=exchserver-2019)** to the shared mailbox by creating a transport rule(**[Append the HTML disclaimer
/ Apply a HTML disclaimer to the message](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/security-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/mail-flow-rule-actions)**). The following rule is for your reference:

[image]

If you grant the **Send As** permission of the shared mailbox to users, after they "**send as**" the shared mailbox, the recipients will receive emails with a disclaimer(signature):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

But how can I set different signatures for two different users who will send emails from a shared inbox? I've tried the above disclaimer and either no signature was appended or both were appended to an email.